# Microsoft Graph SharePoint List Items Not Expanded Correctly

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a SharePoint list and I'm using the Microsoft Graph API v1.0 (also tried beta) to get list items as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).  As it suggests, I am using the `expand=fields` but my list has a person field (Engineer) which via OData I was able to expand and then use syntax like "Engineer/Title" and "Engineer/Email".  This does not appear to work.  How can I get this capability back using the Graph API?  Thanks.

Comment: Just giving a thought, try this call where you can see some data on Engineer property `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteid/lists/listid/items/itemid/fields` and see if you can see the Engineer property so that we could know if expand query parameter has an issue or if there is no field something like that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  I just get `EngineerLookupId` and none of the additional fields.  Seems crazy that I'm now going to have to do another lookup for *each* record just to get engineer details :(

Comment: Have you tried select in expand `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteid/lists/listid?$expand=fields($select=engineerLookupId, engineerLookupName)`. Something like this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247600/expand-multiple-lookup-field-with-microsoft-graph.

Comment: Try the above steps shared by @ShivaKeshavVarma to see if it works. If not, consider creating a [new uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359605) so that they can consider it to be implemented.